# Error in vb.net with paramaters while inserting in sqlite3 database

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I got a  error 'Abort due to constraint violation column transid not unique' while inserting in a sqlite3 database. Here are my codes, can someone please help me?

```
Public Connection As SQLiteConnection
Public Function Getconnection() As SQLiteConnection
    Connection = New SQLiteConnection
    Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\POS.s3db; Version=3;"
    Connection.Open()
    GetConnection = Connection
End Function

Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(strSQL,Connection)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            strSQL = "insert into tbltrans2 (transid,itemcode,flddate,itemname,qty,price,total,btw,btwper) values ('@tid',@itemcode,'@date','@itemname','@qty','@price','@total','@btw',@btwper)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tid", txtTransId.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", txtDate.Text)
            ''this is temp

            For Each ls As ListViewItem In ListItems.Items
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("itemcode", ls.Tag)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("itemname", ls.SubItems(0).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("qty", ls.SubItems(1).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("price", ls.SubItems(2).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("total", ls.SubItems(3).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("btw", (Double.Parse(ls.SubItems(5).Text) / 100) * (Double.Parse(ls.SubItems(3).Text)).ToString("#,##0.00"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("btwper", Double.Parse(ls.SubItems(5).Text))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next ls
        End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a `unique` constraint on `transid`.  That means you can't insert a row with a `transid` that already exists in the table.

Try entering a different `transid`, or setting `transid` as an [auto-increment column](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), so you don't haver to enter it at all.

Comment: The error message says that there is a unique constraint on it.  Double check your database definition?